# How to prevent script (via \immediate\write18) from running multiple times?

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, shell-escape, scripts

How to prevent the execution of script (via `\immediate\write18`) multiple times when running latexmk (which calls pdftex multiple times)? The problem is that during each iteration of pdftex, the script called by `\immediate\write18` is executed.

One solution, albeit very rudimentary, is to have the script create a temp file, and to stop execution if it finds it. But surely there is a more elegant way of handling this...

I'm sure it's not relevant to the question, but I'm using Linux and the script is a simple bash command.

Comment: you need to do as you say or usually if the script is generating something test if the thing is there and just run if not, eg to include an EPS file into pdflatex the graphics package tests if a matching pdf exists and if not calls epstopdf to make one.

Comment: There is in general no way to store state between tex runs other than the filesystem so testing something on the filesystem is the only option really. I am not sure why you say it is rudimentary

Comment: It's rudimentary (in my view), because generally, I'd have to create a new temp file and delete it afterwards (more read / writes on a SSD). Also, deletion of said file would have to be manually, as the script would not know if a new iteration is due.

Comment: Without knowing what the script does and under what circumstances it should or should not be run, it's impossible to help.

Comment: The script is a simple bash script to check if a given URL is broken or not (using curl). If the HTTP code returned is either 200 or 301, then the link is ok, if not, the script just creates a pop-up (using notify-send in Ubuntu to see a pop-up on my desktop), alerting me that there is a broken link I need to fix. Nothing is actually written anywhere. I have numerous links I'd like to check, so I'd like for this simple URL verification to be done once (it's also time consuming).

Comment: Then maybe you can have the script maintain a small SQLite database with the url, status, and date of the last check, and have the script check an url only if it is new or if the last check for that url was too long ago (say 1 day or 1 week). This still impacts the SSD, but with each LaTeX run there are already a _lot_ of files read and written (packages, fonts, logs, aux file, pdf, possibly images, table of contents files, bibliography, etc. etc.) so one more read-write will not make the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to replicate what latexmk does in determining the number of pdflatex iterations required, and replicate it.

However, as commented by others, the easiest is indeed to rely of storing the status on a file and read it during execution.

Since I never clean the generated files, the approach I've followed is to check for the existence of the .fdb_latexmk (generated at the very end of running latexmk) and if it exists delete it and run the scripts. If it does not exist then do nothing.

Not the most elegant answer but does work indeed.